# Jagged edge of circle

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, contour

I am using LiDAR data to locate Sinkholes(depressions) in an area. I am doing this by making the contours and checking the contours(if they are circular enough or not, elongatedness, etc.). But I have a problem, I need to check the jaggedness of the circle edge, so If it is too jagged, I eliminate that contour. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of what you are trying to do? I would also suggest that there are better tools for detecting sinkholes using a DEM created from the LiDAR rather than the contours.

Comment: Try using the 'Smooth Line' Tool to clean up your contour lines and get rid of the "jaggedness".
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000012000000

Editing contour lines is usually a very time consuming process, but providing screenshots will help me understand much more. I want to see exactly what you mean by jaggedness, are there gaps in the contour lines, are the intervals between the contour lines even, etc.

Comment: @TheGofGIS I do not want to get rid of the contours jaggedness, I need to determine the jaggedness and see if it is above the threshold. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use the sink tool in the spatial analyst toolbox to identify sinks in a raster surface.  Still, if you are dependent on the jagged polygons idea...ensure that the attribute table is populated with the lengths of the jagged lines Generate a 1 meter buffer around the polygons, then calculate the lengths of the buffers.  Compare the two lengths.  A higher difference in lengths means a more jagged polygon.